# Accessing referring object with GenericForeignKey in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
Class A(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(...)

class B(models.Model)
   title = models.CharField()

   def save(*args, **kwargs):
     # Based on the title field I want to fetch some picture and then save the thumbnail in A
```

I have more classes like B which should be referenced from A (this is why I use GenericForeignKey). The problem I am trying to figure out is how to save the thumbnail field (on A) when I am in the `save()` method in B. Inserting many if statement in A to check the type of the referenced class and save the thumbnail accordingly is pretty cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking [at the docs, you can add a reverse generic relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) from `B` to `A`:

> If you know which models you’ll be using most often, you can also add a “reverse” generic relationship to enable an additional API

```
class A_Model(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(...)

class B_Models(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField()
    a_models = generic.GenericRelation(A_Model)
```

and now you can do:

```
 b = B_Model()
 a = A_Model(content_object=b, thumbnail=...)
 a.save()
 b.a_models.all()
```

Comment: Hey Timmy. thanks for the answer.. the last piece of code could have been done without generic relation (correct me if i'm wrong). The problem is that I don't always have control over the order of objects creation (in the admin panel for example, where A object is created by the admin script)